# How to eliminate some part of text from string

Tags: iphone

I am new to iphone.I have facing some issue.I have a list of strings such as
1.mp3
2.mp3
3.mp3
here i want to eliminate all .mp3 and get only the number 1,2,3 how it is possible.If any body know this please help me..

Comment: use `componentsSeparatedByString:` method. http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=532591

Answer (score 2):

If the item you want to remove is always a file extension:

```
NSString *strippedString = [filename stringByDeletingPathExtension];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString * str =@"1.mp3";

if ([str hasSuffix:@".mp3"])
{
    str = [str stringByDeletingPathExtension];
    NSLog(@"%@",str);

}
```